# Reverse for 'django_markdown_preview' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django, django-templates, markdown

In Django 1.8, get this error

```
Reverse for 'django_markdown_preview' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

when I get this `edit_profile.html` template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load django_markdown %}
...

      <form action="/profile/edit/{{profile.user}}/" method="post"  enctype='multipart/form-data' >{% csrf_token %}       
       ...           
                    <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.aboutme.errors }}
                            <label for="aboutme">About me</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="aboutme">{{form.aboutme | markdown }}</textarea>
                    </div>                    

                            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit"  value="Update" />
    </form>
```

Here is the views:

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request, username):
        profile = request.user.profile

        if request.user == profile.user:
                if request.method == 'POST':
                        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=profile)
                        if form.is_valid():
                            f = form.save(commit = False)
                            f.aboutme = form.cleaned_data['aboutme']

                            f.save() 
                            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/%s/' % request.user)                           
                else:
                    user=request.user
                    profile=user.profile
                    form=UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

                args = {}

                args.update(csrf(request))
                args['profile'] = profile
                args['form'] = form
                args['upload_url'] = settings.IMG_UPLOAD_URL
                return render_to_response('userprofile/edit_profile.html', args,
                                          context_instance = RequestContext(request))
        else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")
```

The profile is created and I see the field being filled in the database.

The odd thing is that [markdown](https://github.com/klen/django_markdown) works perfectly well elsewhere. I've also tried `{{form.aboutme }}` and builtin `{{ form.as_ul }}` to reder the template but got the same error, of which I'm clueless and appreciate your hints.

Comment: Show your urls.py. You possibly forgot to add markdown urls: `url('^markdown/', include( 'django_markdown.urls')),`

Comment: Dude you spotted it! Don't know why it was commented out!